# How to populate the selected row in different binding in adf faces?

Tags: java, oracle-adf

I have a **readonly view Object** named **MasterVVO** and an **updatable View object** named **MasterVO**. Both the View Objects are mapped to the same entity object.
I have a page with a **updatable form** having save button. The form is binded to a **MasterVOIterator** of **MasterVO**. I also have a **table** binded to a **MasterVVOIteratorBinding** of **MasterVVO**.

I am new to ADF. please clarify my doubt
***Here is my question:***

1) On selection of the row in a table the currentSelected row information has to be populated in the form. Now the table and the form has different bindings, How can we populate the selected row as part of the form?

Any suggestions are granted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since they share the same key, [SetCurrentRowWithKey](https://blogs.oracle.com/raghuyadav/entry/setcurrentrowwithkey_and_setcu) should do it. Remember to use the Partial Trigger to have the form refresh itself when the row is selected. The table will be the partial trigger to the form.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution in the declarative way. Because the two view objects are from same EntityObject, it can be done in a declarative way.Here are the steps:

1) Go to the XXXPageDef.xml file and select the MasterVVOIteratorBinding from the bindings section
2) select the edit button
3) Expand the Target Data Source section. 
4) From the EL Picker button select the MasterVOIterator (#{bindings.MasterVOIteratorBinding}).

By following the above steps, the selected item got populated.

Note:
It can either be done in programmatic way as well:
for this for the rowSelection listener we should get the selected rowKey and should set for the MasterVOIteratorBindinding by invoking  SetCurrentRowWithKey method.